# How to set PopUpWindow to be on the same monitor as the application? (xaf)

Tags: winforms, .net-core, xaf

The user often moves my XAF Winforms app between monitors.
However dialogs invoked by the [PopUpWindowShowAction](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions.PopupWindowShowAction?p=net5) remain on the old monitor

This issue can be repeated with Dev Express's Main Demo ( although to debug it there I think I would need to get into the API code).

1. Run Main Demo and move the application window to the second monitor.
2. Select Users, right click a user and select Print Preview.

The Print Preview will appear on the first monitor.

In my similar case, my controller is

```
public partial class JobHeadFilterController : ViewController, IClassicController
{
    public JobHeadFilterController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TargetViewNesting = Nesting.Root;
    }

    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
        popupWindowShowFilterAction.QuickAccess = true;
    }

    private void popupWindowShowFilterAction_CustomizePopupWindowParams(object sender,
        CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs e)
    {
        var holder = new JobHeadFilterHolder();
        var npProvider = new NonPersistentObjectSpaceProvider(XafTypesInfo.Instance, null);
        var os = (NonPersistentObjectSpace)npProvider.CreateObjectSpace();
        var view = Application.CreateDetailView(os, holder);
        e.View = view;
    }
```

I have tried browsing the properties of CustomizePopupWindowParamsEventArgs  but cant see what to set.

I can get the main form using

```
 var mainform = Application.MainWindow.Template as Form;
```

I think I need to do something like the following inside popupWindowShowFilterAction_CustomizePopupWindowParams

```
            var template = e.Application.MainWindow.Template;
            var window = new Window(Application, );  // having trouble figuring out the parameters
            e.DialogController.SetWindow(window);
```

Studying [the docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112805/ui-construction/controllers-and-actions/dialog-controller)

[Update]

I tried

var window = e.Application.MainWindow;
e.DialogController.SetWindow(window);

but got an error

> The 'DevExpress.ExpressApp.SystemModule.DialogController' controller
> is active.

I tried making my own dialog controller inheriting from the Dev DevExpress.ExpressApp.SystemModule.DialogController but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Templates;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Templates;
namespace MyNameSpace;
 
public partial class CustomizeFormsWindowController : WindowController
{
    public CustomizeFormsWindowController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TargetWindowType = WindowType.Child;
    }

    protected override void OnActivated()
    {
        base.OnActivated();
        Window.TemplateChanged += WindowsTemplateChanged;
    }

    private void WindowsTemplateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Window.Template is Form &&
            Window.Template is ISupportStoreSettings)
            ((ISupportStoreSettings)Window.Template).SettingsReloaded +=
                OnFormReadyForCustomizations;
    }

    private void OnFormReadyForCustomizations(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not PopupForm popupForm) return;
        var mainForm = Application.MainWindow.Template as Form;
        var X = mainForm.Location.X + (mainForm.Width - popupForm.Width) / 2;
        var Y = mainForm.Location.Y + (mainForm.Height - popupForm.Height) / 2;
        popupForm.SetDesktopLocation(X, Y);
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivated()
    {
        Window.TemplateChanged -= WindowsTemplateChanged;
        base.OnDeactivated();
    }
}
```